# How to Check if the file is in a specific path / local site

Tags: php

I am asking if I can check a specific path in a Local website

For example, this path of the image may not work for you, but it works for me because this site only works within the communication network of my area

*https://movie.vodu.me/image/s3/images/604b2c42aa9f6.jpg*

I tried a function **file_exists
**

But it gives me that the file does not exist with all the possibilities I can appreciate because in this function the verification is done through the server and not through my browser and through the server he does not see the image for sure because the image is local

I hope my question is clear, and I thank you for your help

Comment: Unfortunately, no, because I am dealing with my question with my local site

Comment: If you run your code from a machine which is in the same local network then you should be able to check it. If you don't, then you can't

Comment: I actually did this, but it is on a server that is not local and it does not find the file

Comment: Let’s ignore “local”, that word could mean or imply things that can muddy the waters. Instead, there is a server somewhere that when you access a specific URL in your browser you get something (presumably an image, but doesn’t matter). If I try to access it, it won’t work. The solution is to mimic your browser. Could be a cookie, could be a proxy, could be a browser extension, could be IP-related, could be dozens of things. Figure out why your browser can get to it, what “rules” or logic are being used, then go from there.